# How to Auto-Update or Auto-Delete Google Calendar Events when Cells are Updated in the Google Sheet the Event is Created From From?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have reviewed other answers to seemingly similar questions and haven't been able to find a solution yet. I am currently using the below script (thanks to a lot of help!) to auto-populate events from multiple sheets in a workbook; however, what I am also hoping to achieve:

1. the events auto update in the calendar if pre-existing data in C4:F24 is changed (without a duplicate event being created)
2. the event deletes if data in cells E4:F24 is deleted.

I already have an "onEdit" trigger enabled; however, it does not allow for any of the above. Any help is incredibly appreciated!  I have updated the script to reflect what I am currently testing.  This script returns the following error when the installed "OnEdit" trigger runs: ReferenceError: e is not defined
at simpleSheetsToCalendar(Code:4:17)

```js
function simpleSheetsToCalendar() {
  var sheetNames = ["Oct-08-2021 | Plan", "Oct-15-2021 | Plan"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.
  var calendarId = "myCalendar"; // Please set your calendar ID.
  var {range} = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (!(sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) && range.rowStart >= 4 && range.rowEnd <= 24 && range.columnStart >= 3 && range.columnStart <= 6)) return;

  // 1. Retrieve all events from the Calendar and create an object for checking the duplicated titles.
  var events = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var res = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {maxResults: 2500, fields: "nextPageToken,items(id,summary,start(dateTime),end(dateTime))", pageToken});
    events = events.concat(res.items);
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);
  var obj = events.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.summary]: e}), {});

  // 2. Retrieve sheets from a Google Spreadsheet and retrieve the values from "C4:F24", and create an object for creating new events, deleting events and updating events.
  var values = sheet.getRange("C4:F24").getValues().reduce((o, [title,,startTime,endTime]) => {
    if (!obj[title] && title && startTime && endTime && !o[title]) {
      o.add[title] = {startTime, endTime};
    } else if (obj[title] && title && startTime && endTime) {
      if (new Date(obj[title].start.dateTime).getTime() != startTime.getTime() || new Date(obj[title].end.dateTime).getTime() != endTime.getTime()) {
        obj[title].start.dateTime = startTime;
        obj[title].end.dateTime = endTime;
        o.modify.push(obj[title]);
      }
    } else if (obj[title] && title && !startTime && !endTime) {
      o.remove.push(obj[title].id);
    }
    return o;
  }, {add: {}, remove: [], modify: []});

  // 3. Create new events.
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var ar = Object.entries(values.add);
  if (ar.length > 0) {
    ar.forEach(([title, {startTime, endTime}]) => eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime));
  }

  // 4. Modify events.
  if (values.modify.length > 0) {
    values.modify.forEach(({id, start, end}) => eventCal.getEventById(id).setTime(start.dateTime, end.dateTime));
  }

  // 5. Delete events.
  if (values.remove.length > 0) {
    values.remove.forEach(id => eventCal.getEventById(id).deleteEvent());
  }
}
```

Comment: You should better first try [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) yourself.

Comment: thank you, the trigger is already enabled. sorry for not making that clear; however the trigger does not allow for the events to auto update or delete if changes are made.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the events auto update in the calendar`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, about `the event deletes if data in cells E4:F24 is deleted.`, in this case when the values of columns "E" and "F" are deleted while the value of column "C" is existing, you want to delete the event?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of the trigger.

Comment: so, if I change the time in cells E or F, I would like the event to update to the new time in the calendar. and yes!  similarly, if I delete the times for the event in E or F, I would like the event to delete even if there is data in C.  idfurw: Regarding the trigger, that wasn't done via code I wrote.  I just set up and added a trigger to run "on edit"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you SO incredibly much, this is amazing. It seems like you understood what I am trying to do perfectly! I'm sorry to be so dense, but could please explain this in another way? "When you run the script, please edit the cells "C4:C24" of the specific sheets of sheetNames. Please be careful this." I am getting the "e is not defined" error, so I'm definitely not doing it right.  I've tried editing those specific cells in the specific sheets of sheetNames and still get the error when I run the script.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following question and your replying,

> - the events auto update in the calendar if pre-existing data in C4:F24 is changed (without a duplicate event being created)

> - the event deletes if data in cells E4:F24 is deleted.

In your situation, I understood as follows.

- You want to automatically execute the script when the cells "C4:C24" of the specification sheets are edited.
- When the columns "E" and "F" are changed while the column "C" has the value, you want to change the start and endtime of the event.
- When the cells "E4:F24" are deleted while the cells "C4:C24" are not deleted, you want to delete the events from the calendar.

In this case, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve all events from the Calendar and create an object for checking the duplicated titles.
2. Retrieve sheets from a Google Spreadsheet and retrieve the values from "C4:F24", and create an object for creating new events, deleting events and updating events.
3. When new title is found, create new events.
4. When the title is existing and the start and end times are changed, modify events.
5. When the title is existing and the start and end times are deleted, Delete events.

And, in order to execute the script, in this case, the installable OnEdit trigger is used. Because Calendar API is used. When this flow is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this sample script, in order to retrieve all titles of the calendar event, Calendar API is used. So before you use this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set `sheetNames` and `calendarId`.

And also, [please install the installable OnEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to the function `simpleSheetsToCalendar`.

```js
function simpleSheetsToCalendar(e) {
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.
  var calendarId = "calendarId"; // Please set your calendar ID.
  var {range} = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (!(sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) && range.rowStart >= 4 && range.rowEnd <= 24 && range.columnStart >= 3 && range.columnStart <= 6)) return;

  // 1. Retrieve all events from the Calendar and create an object for checking the duplicated titles.
  var events = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var res = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {maxResults: 2500, fields: "nextPageToken,items(id,summary,start(dateTime),end(dateTime))", pageToken});
    events = events.concat(res.items);
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);
  var obj = events.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.summary]: e}), {});

  // 2. Retrieve sheets from a Google Spreadsheet and retrieve the values from "C4:F24", and create an object for creating new events, deleting events and updating events.
  var values = sheet.getRange("C4:F24").getValues().reduce((o, [title,,startTime,endTime]) => {
    if (!obj[title] && title && startTime && endTime && !o[title]) {
      o.add[title] = {startTime, endTime};
    } else if (obj[title] && title && startTime && endTime) {
      if (new Date(obj[title].start.dateTime).getTime() != startTime.getTime() || new Date(obj[title].end.dateTime).getTime() != endTime.getTime()) {
        obj[title].start.dateTime = startTime;
        obj[title].end.dateTime = endTime;
        o.modify.push(obj[title]);
      }
    } else if (obj[title] && title && !startTime && !endTime) {
      o.remove.push(obj[title].id);
    }
    return o;
  }, {add: {}, remove: [], modify: []});

  // 3. Create new events.
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var ar = Object.entries(values.add);
  if (ar.length > 0) {
    ar.forEach(([title, {startTime, endTime}]) => eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime));
  }

  // 4. Modify events.
  if (values.modify.length > 0) {
    values.modify.forEach(({id, start, end}) => eventCal.getEventById(id).setTime(start.dateTime, end.dateTime));
  }

  // 5. Delete events.
  if (values.remove.length > 0) {
    values.remove.forEach(id => eventCal.getEventById(id).deleteEvent());
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the events for updating and deleting are retrieved from all event lists from Calendar and the values from Spreadsheet. And, when the values of columns "E" and "F" are changed, the event with the title of column "C" is updated. When the values of columns "E" and "F" are empty, the event with the title of column "C" is deleted.

#### Note:

- In this answer, from your question, it supposes that when the values of columns "E" and "F" are removed, the values of the title of column "C" are existing. Please be careful about this.
- **In this modified script, the script is automatically executed when the cells "C4:F24" of the specification sheets. So when you directly run the function, an error like `Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. When you run the script, please edit the cells "C4:F24" of the specific sheets of `sheetNames`. Please be careful this.**
- **Please confirm your sheet names. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [setTime(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#settimestarttime,-endtime)
- [deleteEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#deleteevent)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. Can you comment to my answer? Because I cannot notice your comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: @athombomb About `I am getting the "e is not defined" error, so I'm definitely not doing it right.`, your question says `How to Auto-Update or Auto-Delete Google Calendar Events when Cells are Updated in the Google Sheet the Event is Created From From?`. So this script is run by the installable OnEdit trigger. Also, you said `the trigger is already enabled`. By the way, the cells `C4:C24` is my mistake. I deeply apologize for this. In this script, when the cells `C4:F24` are edited, the script is run.

Comment: @athombomb By the way, you want to run the script by OnEdit trigger? Or you want to directly run the script with the script editor? You say `How to Auto-Update or Auto-Delete Google Calendar Events when Cells are Updated in the Google Sheet the Event is Created From From?` and `the trigger is already enabled` in your question and comment. From this, I thought that you want to run script by OnEdit trigger.

Comment: @athombomb 
But in your latest comment, you say `I am getting the "e is not defined" error, so I'm definitely not doing it right. I've tried editing those specific cells in the specific sheets of sheetNames and still get the error when I run the script.`. In this case, you don't want to run with OnEdit trigger?

Comment: @athombomb From this situation, unfortunately, from your question and replying, I'm confusing your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I can't seem to find how to comment directly to your answer.  hopefully tagging you helps!  You're right!  The trigger is already enabled and I do think that's likely the most efficient way for the script to be run.  I looked at logs and apparently, the trigger has been failing every time. Do you happen to have any idea how to fix that, or what might be causing it to fail? I deleted the trigger and added another "on edit" trigger, but it's failing as well. I found the trigger error detail: Oct 13, 2021, 7:47:36 PM Error ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at simpleSheetsToCalendar(Code:4:17)

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script using my proposed script for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, you want to run the script by installable OnEdit trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: your skill is fantastic, no apologies! Your understanding is correct.  For some reason, I cannot add script to the sample spreadsheet, but here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPx_4ZkdSoWLNeYav_PG0JOec41Ab2yGIs__rVsf4L0/edit#gid=1705676457.   The installable OnEdit trigger, for me, is failing and returning: e is not defined at simpleSheetsToCalendar(Code:4:17)

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. About `For some reason, I cannot add script to the sample spreadsheet`, in this case, I cannot replicate your current issue. In order to correctly understand it, can you add your current script using my proposed script to your question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: you got it. I updated my original question with the current code I'm using based on your script.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for adding your current script. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your current script, I noticed an issue. You use the sheet names of `var sheetNames = ["Oct-08-2021 | Plan", "Oct-15-2021 | Plan"];`. But your sample Spreadsheet has 3 sheets of `Skip this sheet`, `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`. How about this?

Comment: Yes, my sample spread sheet has different sheet names, so the script I shared reflects the sheet names of the live spread sheet.

Comment: @athombomb Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. As the result, what sheet names do you want to use?

Comment: the sheet names in the script are accurate to the live spreadsheet, so those will be used in the script I push live.

Comment: @athombomb By the way, when I saw your added script, you are not using the event object `e`. It's `function simpleSheetsToCalendar() {`. My proposed script is `function simpleSheetsToCalendar(e) {`. I thought that this might be the reason of your current issue. Because when I tested your sample Spreadsheet by running my proposed script with the installable OnEdit trigger, no error occurs. How about this?

Comment: OMG!!!! YOU'RE RIGHT!!!!!!  Great catch.  I cut and paste, I have no idea how that happened and I missed that.  THAT was the issue!!.  THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!!  The script is working great now!! THANK. YOU!!!  I accepted your solution and will mark my question solved.  THANK YOU!!!!!  Did I say thank you?  :)